# Reverse a list of characters

Tags: javascript

```
list = [c,a,r,p,e,t]

function reverse(list) {
  var i =0; j= list.length-1;
  while(i < j) {
    var temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[j];
    list[j] = temp;
    i++;
    j--;
  }
  return list;
}
```

Hello everyone, I am trying to solve the problem above. It works for an array of numbers. How can I adapt it to handle a list of characters?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined` Did you mean to use strings instead?

Comment: step 1: `list = ['c','a','r','p','e','t']`

Comment: You can just do `list.reverse()`? You might want to google first buddy :)

Comment: yeah if I use strings the above logic works as well. By the way thanks everyone for the solutions. However I was asked in an interview in above format list = [c,a,r,p,e,t] . I was not sure whether we should use strings or not. Any thoughts was I suppose to ask interviewer about using strings. I know this is kind of a silly question?Need help

Answer (score 2):

Arrays can be reversed by design natively without the needs of a loop:

```
var list = ['c','a','r','p','e','t'];

var reversedList = list.slice(0).reverse();
```

Check the [Mozilla Developer Network: Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) and [Mozilla Developer Network: Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for more infomation.

Comment: I've modified the example to not being operating `in-place` thanks for notifing me about this.

Comment: the OP's issue is `c, a, r, p, e, t` should've been `'c','a','r','p','e','t'` - OP's code "works" (albeit it's not the best way to do it) as is as long as the array is initialised correctly

Answer (score 0):

just use `.reverse();` and assuming `c,a,r,p,e,t` is a variable then use `String()` if you want to sort it by letter and use `Number()` if sort it by number.

sort by string:

```
var list = [String(c),String(a),String(r),String(p),String(e),String(t)].reverse();
```

sort by number:

```
var list = [Number(c),Number(a),Number(r),Number(p),Number(e),Number(t)].reverse();
```

Reference: [.reverse()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp) [String()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp) [Number(](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp))

Comment: the OP's issue is `c, a, r, p, e, t` which you've corrected without explanation

Comment: I just edited my code above and explain what is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws - **Uncaught ReferenceError: c is not defined**. As you miss to place " or ' along with character.

Change your step array declaration step  :

**From** : list = [c,a,r,p,e,t]
To : list = ['c','a','r','p','e','t'] **or** list = ["c","a","r","p","e","t"]

Your working code

```
var list = ['c','a','r','p','e','t']; 
function reverse(list) {
  var i =0; j= list.length-1;
  while(i < j) {
  var temp = list[i];
  list[i] = list[j];
  list[j] = temp;
  i++;
  j--;
}
return list;

}



//Call the method;
reverse(list);
```

jsfiddle working example :

https://jsfiddle.net/m6kt3eus/1/

**Other simpler way to achieve this :**
The simple way to reverse the array is reverse() in javascript

Following are the example code snippet:

```
var list = ['c','a','r','p','e','t'];
list.reverse();
console.log(list);
```

**arr.reverse()** is used for in place reversal of the array. The first element of the array becomes the last element and vice versa.

**Syntax:**

```
arr.reverse()
```

**Argument**
This function does not take any argument.

**Return value**
This function returns the reference of the reversed original array.

Comment: Didn't get you, please help me to understand what do you mean ?

Comment: `array.reverse` reverses array - and I just re-read the code in the OP and realise  you're right - but there's no need for `var new_list = ...` because `list` will be reversed

Comment: however, the OP's problem is `c, a, r, p, e, t` are not **strings**

Comment: 'var new_list = ... because list will be reversed ' - Thanks for this info

I've edited the code with adding more explanation

Comment: you still haven't actually addressed the *only* issue in the question, you've fixed it, but haven't explained why `c, a, r, p, e, t` fails, but `'c','a','r','p','e','t'` works

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverse(list) {
    var list2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        list2.unshift(list[i]);
    return list2;
}

var list = ['c', 'a', 'r', 'p', 'e', 't'];
console.log(reverse(list));
```